# can i show data with Pagination in two different html pages from views using Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

hello i want show data with pagination in two different html pages

i mean i have model called `PCgames` and i want pass data to ( two different html page )

i have added this in `views.py` :

```
def pc_games(request):
app = PCgames.objects.all()
page = request.GET.get('pc-games-page', 1) # the_home_page is the name of pages when user go to page 2 etc
paginator = Paginator(app, 6) # 6 that's mean it will show 6 apps in page
try:
    pc_Games_one = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    pc_Games_one = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    pc_Games_one = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request,'html_file/pc_games.html', { 'pc_Games_one': pc_Games_one })
```

this code is render to `pc_games.html` and i want pass same data to `home.html`

how i can do that ?

Comment: I see only two ways, change http request to json request, and make ajax requests from front to back and there will be one function, or just make function for each page separated, because way be in future you need to 10 objects in one page, for another html 50

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen OK thank you I prefer the second way ( use function )
Can you give me an example please ?